# How to copy and overwrite all the data (files and folders) from one one folder to another automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, copy

I am trying to set up a google drive automoation using Apps Script, which would copy an entire folder into another folder after every few hours. But I am currently facing a "Time out" issue, may be as the folder is of over 2 GB. Is there a solution to my problem?

I have developed the code as under, but it is getting terminated at 360s saying 'timed out'.

```js
function start() {
  var sourceFolder = 'abc';
  var targetFolder = "xxxxx";
  var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolder);
  var target = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxx");
  if (source.hasNext()) {
    copyFolder(source.next(), target);
  }
}

function copyFolder(source, target) {
  var folders = source.getFolders();
  var files = source.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (target.getFilesByName(file.getName()).hasNext()) {
      var oldFile = target.getFilesByName(file.getName()).next();
      oldFile.setTrashed(true); // Delete the old file in destination folder with the same name
      file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
    } else {
      file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
    }
  }

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    if (target.getFoldersByName(subFolder.getName()).hasNext()) {
      var oldFolder = target.getFoldersByName(subFolder.getName()).next();
      oldFolder.setTrashed(true);
      var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
      copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
    } else {
      var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
      copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have reached the 6min quota : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas?hl=fr#current_limitations I'm afraid there is no solution with your current workflow. A workaround could be to add a gsheet and save your progress, each new execution will start again from where the previous execution ended.

Comment: What's the cause of the time out?

Comment: 'Exceeded maximum time'